# How to set parameters with print multiple in one go with different headings in rdlc report with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq, printing, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm trying to set parameters with print multiple in one go with different headings in rdlc report with VB.NET
I have the code below.
I tried with the code below which came out the result only `COPY1`

Please Guide me

Thanks

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
    Private Sub original()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Columns.Add("value", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("price", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("quantity", GetType(Double))
        table.Rows.Add("test1", "10", "20")
        table.Rows.Add("test2", "10", "20")
        Dim reportDataSource1 = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", table)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        Dim reportParameters As New ReportParameterCollection()
        reportParameters.Add(New ReportParameter("paramHeader", "ORIGINAL"))
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Datatable_in_ReportViewer.Report1.rdlc"
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
    Private Sub copy1()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Columns.Add("value", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("price", GetType(String))
        table.Columns.Add("quantity", GetType(Double))

        table.Rows.Add("test1", "10", "20")
        table.Rows.Add("test2", "10", "20")
        Dim reportDataSource1 = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", table)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
        Dim reportParameters As New ReportParameterCollection()
        reportParameters.Add(New ReportParameter("paramHeader", "COPY1"))
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1)
        Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Datatable_in_ReportViewer.Report1.rdlc"
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        original()
        copy1()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you want to output to separate reports or same report with multiple dataset / tables?

Comment: @HardcoreGamer , I want same report with one table / dataset

Answer (score 0):

Parameter only have single value, you overwrite the second time you add.

```
reportParameters.Add(New ReportParameter("paramHeader", "ORIGINAL"))
reportParameters.Add(New ReportParameter("paramHeader", "COPY1"))
```

Instead, you can try add a new column `Copys` to group two data in same table, with value `ORIGINAL` and `Copy1`

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
MyBase.Load

End Sub
Private Sub original(ByRef table as DataTable))
    table.Rows.Add("original","test1", "10", "20")
    table.Rows.Add("original","test2", "10", "20")
End Sub
Private Sub copy1(ByRef table as DataTable)
    table.Rows.Add("copy1","test1", "10", "20")
    table.Rows.Add("copy1","test2", "10", "20")
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add("Copys", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("value", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("price", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("quantity", GetType(Double))
    original(table)
    copy1(table)
    
    Dim reportDataSource1 = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", table)
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim reportParameters As New ReportParameterCollection()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters)
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1)
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Datatable_in_ReportViewer.Report1.rdlc"
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
End Class
```

You will need to edit the .rdlc report table and group it by the new column `Copys`